# Creating associative entity table

Tags: sql, oracle

The following tables have already been implemented successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient (
Patient_ID  CHAR(5)     CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name  VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Last_Name   VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
DoB     DATE,
 Sex        CHAR(1),
 Phone      NUMBER(10),
 Address    VARCHAR2(40)
);

CREATE TABLE Physician (
Physician_ID    CHAR(5)     CONSTRAINT Physician_PK PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name  VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Last_Name   VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Department_ID   CHAR(5) ,
  CONSTRAINT physician_FK_dept
   FOREIGN KEY (Department_ID)
   REFERENCES Department (Department_ID)
   ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

But when I tried creating the associative entity between the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Visit (
Visit_ID    CHAR(5)     CONSTRAINT Visit_PK PRIMARY KEY,
Visit_date  DATE        NOT NULL,
Patient_ID  VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Physician_ID    VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT visit_FK_patient
   FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID)
   REFERENCES Patient (Patient_ID)
   ON DELETE SET CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT visit_FK_physician
   FOREIGN KEY (Physician_ID)
   REFERENCES Physician (Physician_ID)
   ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

It failed because of an error:

> ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword"

Normally it would be a simple matter of a missing NULL. But this time, no matter how I look at the SQL it doesn't look like that is the error. Can anyone help to see if they can find what the problem is from another perspective? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you have

```
ON DELETE SET CASCADE
```

This should be

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

c.f. [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Foreign_key#ON_DELETE_CASCADE)